# GET request to a third party API using Node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, get

I am trying to GET some JSON data from an API and display the objects in the HTML. I have an index.html, server.js, and a request_json.js file.

request_json.js

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: '',
  path: ''
};

callback = function(res) {
  var str = '';

  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  res.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

index.html

```
...
<body>
  <script src="request_json.js"></script> 
</body>
```

So how do I insert the JSON objects that are returned into the html? When I do it this way, I receive an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Node.js from a webpage then you need to:

1. Use [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and not just give code written to run on Node.js to a web browser. Web browsers are not Node.js, they do not have access to Node.js's APIs. In this context, Node.js is used to write *server side* code, not browser side.
2. Create a way for Node.js and the browser to communicate. This is typically done by writing an HTTP server in Node.js. There is a very basic example on [the Node.js about page](https://nodejs.org/en/about/), more complicated systems tend to use [Express](http://expressjs.com/).
3. Express the data you want to fetch in a form that the browser can understand. JSON is a popular data format, but plain HTML might be more suitable.
4. Get that data to the browser. Typically you would use XMLHttpRequest from JavaScript if the data is in JSON or use a link or form submission to get an HTML version.

Comment: I have completed steps 2 and 3 I believe. I don't know how to display that to the HTML.

Comment: `<a href="http://url_of_your_node_js_server/whatever/path/you/set/up">Click me</a>`